# how to jump is collision with current stack in STACK JUMP game using unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop the popular game stack jump.I am unable to determine how to make the player jump only if it collides with current index stack.my stack gets spawned if the player collides with any of the stacks.Can please someone help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect collison only for the current block or stack, then add 2 capsule colliders, and click on the On trigger box for only one of the 2. Then, for only that block, give this in your script.

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    Debug.Log( “Finished” );
}
```

This might not be the one that'll give the required output, but it'll check for collisions with the current stack. You can change `Debug.Log( “Finished” );` to whatever is required for the according output.